# add php file include woocommerce product description

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to include a timer in the products description of a product for sale, I am using woocommerce.

In woo commerce you get a description box to add the details about the product. This is mainly plain text or images.

I am trying include a file in the section, the file is hosted on same domain for e.g /timer.php

I have tried this

```
<?php
include('timer.php');
?>
```

but woo commerce is stripping the code and displaying as plain text.

Comment: Have look at the [`templates`](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) documentation. You can then include `timer.php` in the template itself or use a hook to include the required file.

Comment: You will need to find the correct template file from within your child theme (make sure you go in your child theme to avoid overwriting your work), I think the file you will need to include from is the .archive-product.php.